# Error:Composer runtime is not compatible with client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

The issue with starting the REST server, I got the error while starting composer-rest-server 
composer version is v0.20.9
composer-rest-server version v0.19.20

Here is the log :

```
  nithin@:~/fabric-tools/fabric-dev-servers$ composer-rest-server
        ? Enter the name of the business network card to use: admin@test-bna
        ? Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: always use namespaces
        ? Specify if you want to use an API key to secure the REST API: No
        ? Specify if you want to enable authentication for the REST API using Passport: No
        ? Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface: No
        ? Specify a key if you want to enable dynamic logging: 
        ? Specify if you want to enable event publication over WebSockets: No
        ? Specify if you want to enable TLS security for the REST API: No

        To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:
        composer-rest-server -c admin@test-bna -n always

        Discovering types from business network definition ...
        Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.20.9) is not 
        compatible with client (0.19.20)
        It will be retried for the next request.
        Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.20.9) is not compatible with client (0.19.20)
        Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.20.9) is not compatible with client (0.19.20)
        at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/nithin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:842:34)
        at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here issue occurs because your composer and composer-rest-server are not compatible means does not same. So you have to upgrade your fabric environment. Run the following a command to upgrade `composer-rest-server`.

1. `npm uninstall -g composer-cli composer-rest-server generator-hyperledger-composer` . For **uninstalling** your already installed tools.

**Install 0.20.9 `composer-cli`**

1. `npm install -g composer-cli@0.20.9`
2. `npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.20.9`
3. `npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer@0.20.9`

If you need locally composer-playground then run `npm install -g composer-playground@0.20.9`

Hope it will help you:)